# How to style Google maps prompt: 'use two fingers to move the map' for mobile devices

Tags: css, google-maps, touch, google-maps-markers, multi-touch

I need to set higher z-index to this prompt window, because the map pins stays over it when appears.

Does anyone knows class or id of it? Or how to make it appear over the pins?

Comment: Are you talking about using Google Maps within the Google Maps apps, or on the website? That information makes a big difference. Do you know if this problem persists on all devices/OS's? There just isn't enough information here to provide an answer.

Comment: Information is pretty enough, if you know what I am talking about. The two finger function was added to help scrolling the site, but not the map if you use one finger, and to scroll the map you need two fingers. I dont think that the application have such a prompt, it doesnt make sence. Moreover, how someone can use css on app? So map is added on my site. I have this problem on my android phone, as well as one friend on iPhone, so I thing its on all mobile devices. No information on internet for editing this prompt. I appreciate if you can help!

Comment: Have you tried downloading Chrome, Firefox, or another browser on the phone to test with?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a hack, but I hope it helps you to accomplish what you are trying to do. I just want to mention that this isn't really supported and may stop working at any time due to that.

The class used is .gm-style-pbc. You can actually make the entire message disappear like so:

```
.gm-style-pbc{
display: none !important
}
```

You should also be able to do some other styling, for example I made the background red and moved the message over to the right:

```
.gm-style-pbc{
  background-color: red !important;
  left: 30px !important;
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can style the message using the hook that @Stephen mentioned, and adjust the z-index using `!important` to override the one applied inline (`z-index: 2`).  Using the inspector, I found that in my code, my markers were on a div that had an inline `z-index: 4;` applied, so I would want to set this prompt to 5 to sit on top of that marker layer.

However, if you adjust this z-index to sit on top of your markers, since this messaging is just `opacity: 0` (not `display:none`) it will block interaction with your markers, if you want to be able to click on them, etc.  To avoid this, you can use `pointer-events: none` to make this prompt non-interactive and in effect "see through" so that you can interact with the stuff behind it.

```
.gm-style-pbc {
    z-index: 5 !important;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

As @Stephen mentioned, this "hook" is not officially supported.